# Is it possible to print extra custom fileds along with the StackTrace while using log4j

Tags: java, error-handling, log4j, stack-trace, exception-logging

I have this program as shown below , right now its only printng the stacktrace .
my question is that , is it possible to get the stack trace and also a custom field , here in my case i  need 1090099

Please tell me if its possible ??

```
package com;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class Test {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
    String accountid = "1090099";
            String desc = null;
            System.out.println(desc.toUpperCase());
            } 
            catch (Exception t) 
        {
            logger.fatal("Exception inside the Test program  ", t);
        }
    }
}

2013-06-26 21:44:29,723[main] FATAL(Test.java:<main>:16)- Exception inside the Test program
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.Test.main(Test.java:12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can print the value as long as it's in scope.

```
String accountid = null;
try {
     accountid = "1090099";
     String desc = null;
     System.out.println(desc.toUpperCase());
 } catch (Exception t) {
     logger.fatal("Exception inside the Test program  " + accountid, t);
 }
```

Also, I would suggest using logger.debug instead of system.out.println for your other logging calls...

Answer (score 2):

You have to include it manually in the message you're logging.  But it looks to me like what you're really looking for is the [MDC](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html) (mapped diagnostic context), a way to store values in a thread-local "context" that can then be used to distinguish between log messages relating to different application-level entities.

```
package com;
import org.apache.log4j.*;
public class Test {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MDC.put("accountid", "1090099");
        try {
            String desc = null;
            System.out.println(desc.toUpperCase());
            } 
            catch (Exception t) 
        {
            logger.fatal("Exception inside the Test program  ", t);
        } finally {
            MDC.remove("accountid");
        }
    }
}
```

You would then include `%X{accountid}` somewhere in your appender's layout pattern and it would include the appropriate MDC entry in every log message, including those logged by third-party code that you call.

Comment: compared to the accepted answer, I think it's fair to say that OP wasn't really looking for MDC... :P good information nonetheless!

Answer (score 1):

I would create my own Exception class, with members to hold the additional information, and a suitable toString() method that displays them. Wrap the original Exception in your custom Exception and add the information you want preserved.

Answer (score 0):

You are close to achieving that.

In your case you will have to declare the `accountid` outside the `try` block and then you can append the `accountid` along with your `Exception inside the Test program` message`

Answer (score 0):

```
String accountid = ""; 

try {
        accountid = "1090099";
        String desc = null;
        System.out.println(desc.toUpperCase());
    } 
        catch (Exception t) 
    {
        logger.fatal("Exception inside the Test program.\nAccount ID: " + accountid, t);
    }
```